# Blocking traffic from specific subnets in GCE firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, google-compute-engine

I know how to add firewalls to allow traffic, but i want to also block APNIC traffic as well. Is there a way to drop traffic from a subnet?  I can't seem to come up wit a set of rules that will do it.

Currently, My network has firewalls in place to allow traffic to the proper ports for my applications. Now I want to add rules to exclude a block of IPs from accessing my application.

What I have tried is creating a rule for a block of IPs, add all tcp and udp ports, then NOT adding any destination tags, thinking if it sees traffic from these subnets, but it has no destination, it will drop it.  That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

By default all the incoming traffic to your GCE network is blocked. You create firewall rules to allow the connection for IP or range of IPs and the port. You can refer to the following article for more information https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls

Comment: I will edit my question to include the fact that I have all the desired traffic coming to my instances, but now i want to block undesirable traffic

Comment: In that case I believe you have two options:
1. You can delete the rule to allow traffic for full network and create multiple rules to allow traffic for IP subnets which i believe might not be ideal for you.
2. The easiest option i believe is to allow all the traffic from GCE firewall and use iptables to block the traffic for the subnet.